# how to set selected value in dropdown based on another value

Tags: c#, razor, dropdown

are there a away i can set the selected value on my dropdown based on the key value

`<add key="ReCreateSoldPart" value="false" />`from my appsetting

```
     <label for="autoCreateSoldPart" datalabel="mydropdown">Auto genopret solgt del&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="autoCreateSoldPart">
            <option value="true">Ja</option>
            <option value="false"Nej</option>
        </select></label

>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select an option in razor, do it as follows;
Using the @Html helper;

```
                @Html.Label("Auto genopret solgt del&nbsp;&nbsp;", new {@for= "autoCreateSoldPart"})
                @{ 
                    var lstSelect = new List<SelectListItem>()
                    {
                        new SelectListItem() { Text="Ja",Value="true"  },
                        new SelectListItem() { Text="Ja",Value="false"  }
                    };

                    lstSelect.ForEach(o =>
                    {
                        if (o.Value== System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReCreateSoldPart"])
                        {
                            o.Selected = true;
                        }
                    });

                }
                @Html.DropDownList("autoCreateSoldPart", lstSelect,new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Use the @Html.DropDown instead. Check the selectListItem property value of each item in List, if it matches your appsetting value, set the selected property to true